# Redis publish from a csv. No error but No data received

Tags: python, csv, redis, publish

Below is my script which inserts data from a csv located on one server into  Redis on another server.  If it worked..

I don't get an error but I don't show any data received on the redis side either.  So Iam not sure which is worse.

```
#!/opt/python/bin/python


import csv
import redis
from redis import StrictRedis

reader = csv.reader(open("/opt/xyzxyz.csv"))
header = reader.next()


client = redis.StrictRedis(host='XXXXXXXXX.XX.XXX.X.XXX', port=6379, db=0)

for row in reader:
    key = "xyzxyz:%s" % (row[0], )
    doc = dict(zip(header, row))

    client.publish(key, doc)
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing from the above process?  Or if there is something I am not doing on the redis side?

This is my first time working with Redis so it is kinda new to me.

Comment: Are you sure `publish` is what you want? It sounds like you want `set`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to be using `client.set(key, doc)` rather than `client.publish(key, doc)`.

[Publish](http://redis.io/commands/publish) has a totally different meaning from [set](http://redis.io/commands/set), which is more likely what you want.

**Edit**

(thanks for accepting, I'm just editing this to make it the actual solution to your problem)

The first parameter of `client.publish` is the channel you're publishing to. It sounds like in your case you're publishing to 'csv_filename:first_entry_of_row`when really you want to be publishing to just`csv_filename`.

Try changing the line `key = "xyzxyz:%s" % (row[0],)` to just `key = "xyzxyz"`.

Comment: My Redis counterpart tells me I need to publish under the topic(my csv file name).  Perhaps that is the root of my confusion.  If I did want to publish would would I need to alter?

Comment: Right now, you're publishing each row under the topic 'csv_filename:first_field_of_row'. If you want to publish under csv name, you should change the assignment of `key = 'xyzxyz'`

Comment: I totally missed.  I totally used a base script from a tutorial and edited it for my use case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Look out for these two things:**

1. Check the bind variable in *redis.conf* file. Either you comment it or add your ip address with space separated. Either bind `192.168.1.100`, `10.0.0.1`, your_ip or just comment that line out.
2. Use client.set function instead of client.push.